# What should be the shape of the validation data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Here is the training data shape and validation data shape.

```
print(data.shape)
print(val_data.shape)

(20000, 120, 120, 1)
(4946, 120, 120, 1)
```

Which means i have 20000 training data and 4946 validation data with the picture height and width of 120.
In the first conv layer i am supposed to pass data in the shape of `input_shape = data.shape[1:]` (120, 120, 1) which i have done here.
In terms of the validation data inside `model.fit()` function, when i pass `validation_data=(val_data.shape[1:], val_label)` is giving error but when i pass `validation_data=(val_data.shape, val_label)` it works. I am a bit confused about this. Sorry is this is a minor query but as i am new to CNN, i am having trouble. I have few questions.

1. How is the model being trained and also giving validation accuracy with this parameter `validation_data=(val_data.shape, val_label)`?
2. Shouldn't i need to change the shape of the validation data similar to the training data as i did in the first conv layer?
3. How can i change the validation data in the shape of `val_data.shape[1:]`?

Here is the complete code of the model.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation="relu", input_shape = data.shape[1:])) 
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2))) 

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation="relu") )
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2))) #max pool window 2x2

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2))) #max pool window 2x2

model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2))) #max pool window 2x2

model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten()) 

model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu", name='firstDenseLayer'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(data, label, batch_size=16, epochs=10, validation_data=(val_data.shape[1:], val_label))
```

Comment: There is no need to change anything, I am not sure why you are asking this, but the input shape only refers to the features, the samples dimension is variable and not part of the input shape, that is why it works with both training and validation data.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.fit()` incorrectly. You have to pass data not shape:

```
model.fit(data, label, batch_size=16, epochs=10, validation_data=(val_data, val_label))
```

Comment: As i have mentioned, when i use `model.fit(data, label, batch_size=16, epochs=10, validation_data=(val_data, val_label))` the model gives no error. That is my question why is it working? The training data set and validation data set have the same amount of dimension. In the first convolution layer i have to set the training data shape as `input_shape = data.shape[1:]`. Shouldn't i need to do the same thing with `val_data` in `model.fit()`?

Answer (score 1):

model.fit expects you to provide validation data in the form of a tuple (data,label). Your validation data is already in the correct shape.  model.fit expects the validation data to have the SAME dimensions as the training data for  height, width, bands. If it is not the same it will throw an error.

Comment: In the first convolution layer i have to set the training data shape as input_shape = data.shape[1:]. Shouldn't i need to do the same thing with val_data in model.fit()?